# Turning on / off script after logging out / in via ssh

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

So here is a problem you guys. Got a linux machine with good cpu and gpu, and I do some machine learning stuff (jupyter notebooks via ssh). I use this remote machine for mining 24/7 so I need to turn off those 2 mining scripts (for cpu and gpu) right after I log in and execute them again right after I log out.

What is the best and easiest way to do this thing automatically?

Comment: Other than sending them signals in your login and logout scripts?

Comment: Look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/ssh-login-hook) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136548/force-command-to-be-run-on-logout-or-disconnect) for login/logout hooks

Comment: Do you always have a single login instance to this remote server ?

Comment: If you're on a systemd-based system, could certainly set up a service that has a dependency on your user account having a session. But that's significantly outside of StackOverflow's scope, being more of a system administration question.

Comment: yeah, maybe some global script on remote machine to handle everything on its own.

Comment: @iamauser yep, always single login instance

Comment: `while [[ -n "$(who)" ]]; do kill -STOP $pid; sleep 1; done; kill -CONT $pid` should work

Comment: Why stop them at all? Just run them at the lowest priority, so that they only get scheduled if there is nothing else to do on the machine.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano gonna try that, thx

Comment: @briancaffey will look into it, thx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one login session at any given time, something like this in your `~/.bashrc` could do the job,

```
function start_script()
{
    if [ ! -f "${HOME}/pidfile" ]; then
        /path/to/script1 &> /path/to/log2 & # Background running job
        _spid=$!
        echo "$_spid" > "${HOME}/pidfile"  # Write each pid to a file
        /path/to/script2 &> /path/to/log1 &
        _spid=$!
        echo "$_spid" >> "${HOME}/pidfile"
    fi
}
start_script

function stop_script() 
{
    while read -r _pid
    do
        kill "$_pid"  # kill pids while exiting
    done <"${HOME}/pidfile"
    rm -f "${HOME}/pidfile" # Remove the pidfile 
    echo Goodbye;
}
trap stop_script EXIT  # run stop_script when exiting from login session
```

Above will run `script1` and `script2` on your login and then kill the processes when you logout (cleanly). `trap` is the key here. You can add more signal to it besides `EXIT`.